# HTML does not render that came responds from POST method

Tags: python, html, flask, visualization

I want to create basic election result visualization using flask,html and js I make sure file exist in folder I can show up on terminal but does not appear on html. What should I do for viewing

If I write city name in html page nothing view but to putting print line  I can see print out,when I keypress on keyboard.

PYTHON

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import os
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def cityElectionResult():
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        input_value = request.form.get('cityName')
        city = input_value.upper() + '.json'
        print(city)
        try:
            df = pd.read_json(city)
            print(df['İlçe Adı'])
            cityTurkey = df["İlçe Adı"].tolist()
            yesVoteCity = df["Evet Oranı"].tolist()
            noVoteCity = df["Hayır Oranı"].tolist()
            return render_template("city.html",
                                   cityTurkey=cityTurkey,
                                   yesVoteCity=yesVoteCity,
                                   noVoteCity=noVoteCity)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            error_message = "Veri bulunamadı."
            return render_template("city.html", error_message=error_message)
    else:
        return render_template('city.html', error_message="")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Evet/Hayır Referandumu</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Evet/Hayır Referandumu Sonuçları</h1>

      # added <div id="turkey"></div>
    <div id="city">
      <form action="/" method="post">
        <label for="cityName">City Name: </label>
        <span><input type="text" name="cityName"id="cityName" /></span>
        <button type="submit" value="citySubmit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      {% if cityTurkey and yesVoteCity and noVoteCity %}
      <script>
        {% raw %}
        var datacity = [
          {
            x: {{ cityTurkey|tojson }},
            y: {{ yesVoteCity|tojson }},
            type: "bar",
            name: "Evet",
            marker: { color: "green" }
          },
          {
            x: {{ cityTurkey|tojson }},
            y: {{ noVoteCity|tojson }},
            type: "bar",
            name: "Hayır",
            marker: { color: "red" }
          }
        ];
    
        var layoutCity = {
          title: "Evet/Hayır Referandumu Sonuçları",
          xaxis: { title: "İlçe Adı" },
          yaxis: { title: "Oy Oranı" }
        };
    
        Plotly.newPlot("city", datacity, layoutCity);
        {% endraw %}
      </script>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

figure out problem and solution

Comment: FIGURE OUT. !!!